# Proper way to crop an SVG?

Tags: svg, crop

I'm totally baffled by SVG images. I want to crop the image to its core content. I want to crop it by specifying its viewbox and/or viewport and/or anything else EXCEPT I do NOT want to change any of the points in the polyline elements. The image as-is renders something like this. (NOTE the border is only for illustration purposes. The border is not actually part of the SVG.)

[image: original]

and I want to crop it so it looks something like this. (NOTE the border again is for illustration purposes only)

[image: cropped]

Given this SVG XML how do I crop it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
    <polyline points="39,340  42,338  47,333  54,322  68,308  83,292  91,277  100,259  106" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="71,299  82,303  95,304  109,302  120,301" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="212,275  228,254  233,233  240,208  239,246  188,278  174,306  158,334  149,351  144,358  140,362  139,362  139,340  179,313  186" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="169,345  174,347  227,333  231,330  330,371  328,374  414,209  410,192  404,183  401,177  398,177  395,179   379,340  385,384  397,414" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How are you trying to crop it. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried setting the viewport to various height, width values and quickly discovered that alone won't work. I also tried setting the viewbox to many different values with some success. The closes I found was viewBox="39 243 378 417" but I'm not 100% sure why that kinda comes close. I've also looked at various permutations for the preserveAspectRatio attribute, and finally tried several combinations of all of the above. I'm just plain lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the svg is inline, you can compute its `viewBox` by using `getBBox()` for the root svg.

Below is an example for your polylines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Compute viewBox</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h3>Compute viewBox</h3>
<div id=svgDiv style='background-color:lightgreen'>
<svg id=mySVG>
    <polyline points="39,340  42,338  47,333  54,322  68,308  83,292  91,277  100,259" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="71,299  82,303  95,304  109,302  120,301" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="212,275  228,254  233,233  240,208  239,246  188,278  174,306  158,334  149,351  144,358  140,362  139,362  139,340  179,313  " style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
    <polyline points="169,345  174,347  227,333  231,330  330,371  328,374  414,209  410,192  404,183  401,177  398,177  395,179   379,340  385,384  397,414" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
</svg>
</div>
<button onClick=fit()>fit</button>
viewVox:<input type=text size=20 id=vbValue />
</center>
</body>
<script>
 //---button--
function fit()
{
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbx=bb.x
    var bby=bb.y
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height
    var vb=[bbx,bby,bbw,bbh]
    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox", vb.join(" ") )
    vbValue.value=vb.join(" ")
    svgDiv.style.width=bbw+"px"
    svgDiv.style.height=bbh+"px"
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The SVG library I have been using on Android doesn't have a getBBox method. (I assume BBox means Bounding Box.) But your sample HTML code did the trick because it showed me that the viewBox is a standard rect structure defined as {x, y, width, height}. Knowing that I was able to do some easy calculations on the points of each polyline to find those four values.

Comment: How calc on NodeJS?